# jquery countdown timer with using robcowie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get during countdown running.

I had used robcowie plugin that is very well.

I want to get time during running and calculate its.

When I click the `get` button time is calculated and when I click again the time is added to the previous time.

How do I do this?

Is plugin what the get time function does?

```js
  jQuery(function($){

  $('.timer').stopwatch().bind('tick.stopwatch', function(e, elapsed){
        if (elapsed == 60000) {
            $('.timer').stopwatch('reset');
        }
    }).stopwatch('start');
    });


//plugin use
(function( $ ){



    function incrementer(ct, increment) {
        return function() { ct+=increment; return ct; };
    }
    
    function pad2(number) {
         return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
    }

    function defaultFormatMilliseconds(millis) {
        var x, seconds, minutes, hours;
        x = millis / 1000;
        seconds = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x /= 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x /= 60;
        // hours = Math.floor(x % 24);
        // x /= 24;
        // days = Math.floor(x);
        return [pad2(minutes), pad2(seconds)].join(':');
    }

    //NOTE: This is a the 'lazy func def' pattern described at http://michaux.ca/articles/lazy-function-definition-pattern
    function formatMilliseconds(millis, data) {
        // Use jintervals if available, else default formatter
        var formatter;
        if (typeof jintervals == 'function') {
            formatter = function(millis, data){return jintervals(millis/1000, data.format);};
        } else {
            formatter = defaultFormatMilliseconds;
        }
        formatMilliseconds = function(millis, data) {
            return formatter(millis, data);
        };
        return formatMilliseconds(millis, data);
    }

    var methods = {
        
        init: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                updateInterval: 1000,
                startTime: 0,
                format: '{HH}:{MM}:{SS}',
                formatter: formatMilliseconds
            };
            
            // if (options) { $.extend(settings, options); }
            
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                
                // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                if (!data) {
                    // Setup the stopwatch data
                    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                    data = settings;
                    data.active = false;
                    data.target = $this;
                    data.elapsed = settings.startTime;
                    // create counter
                    data.incrementer = incrementer(data.startTime, data.updateInterval);
                    data.tick_function = function() {
                        var millis = data.incrementer();
                        data.elapsed = millis;
                        data.target.trigger('tick.stopwatch', [millis]);
                        data.target.stopwatch('render');
                    };
                    $this.data('stopwatch', data);
                }
                
            });
        },
        
        start: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                // Mark as active
                data.active = true;
                data.timerID = setInterval(data.tick_function, data.updateInterval);
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        },
        
        stop: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                clearInterval(data.timerID);
                data.active = false;
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        },
        
        destroy: function() {
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                $this.stopwatch('stop').unbind('.stopwatch').removeData('stopwatch');
            });
        },
        
        render: function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('stopwatch');
            $this.html(data.formatter(data.elapsed, data));
        },

        getTime: function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('stopwatch');
            return data.elapsed;
        },
        
        toggle: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                if (data.active) {
                    $this.stopwatch('stop');
                } else {
                    $this.stopwatch('start');
                }
            });
        },
        
        reset: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                data.incrementer = incrementer(data.startTime, data.updateInterval);
                data.elapsed = data.startTime;
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        }
    };
    
    
    // Define the function
    $.fn.stopwatch = function( method ) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.stopwatch' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Time:
    <span class="timer">0:00</span>
</div>
<button>get time</button>
<div>
you get time:
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get time using `$('.timer').text()` directly or you can use stopwatch method `getTime`

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .row{width: 600px;}
    .col{float:left; width: 200px;}
    .f-left{width: 200px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Time:
    <span class="timer">0:00</span>
</div>
<button>get time</button>
<div>
you get time:
</div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>no</th>
                <th>sec</th>
                <th>ms</th>
                <th>total</th>
                <th>totalms</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){

    var stopwatch = $('.timer').stopwatch().bind('tick.stopwatch', function(e, elapsed){
        if (elapsed == 60000) {
            $('.timer').stopwatch('reset');
        }
    }).stopwatch('start');
        var no = 0;
        var total = 0;
        $('button').click(function(){
            no++;
            var timer1 = $('.timer').text(); 
            var timer2 = stopwatch.stopwatch('getTime');
            total += timer2;
            $('table tbody').prepend('<tr><td>'+no+'</td><td>'+timer1+'</td><td>'+timer2+'</td><td>'+millisToMinutesAndSeconds(total)+'</td><td>'+total+'</td></tr>');
        })
    });

    function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
        var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
        var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
        return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
    }

//plugin use
(function( $ ){



    function incrementer(ct, increment) {
        return function() { ct+=increment; return ct; };
    }

    function pad2(number) {
         return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
    }

    function defaultFormatMilliseconds(millis) {
        var x, seconds, minutes, hours;
        x = millis / 1000;
        seconds = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x /= 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(x % 60);
        x /= 60;
        // hours = Math.floor(x % 24);
        // x /= 24;
        // days = Math.floor(x);
        return [pad2(minutes), pad2(seconds)].join(':');
    }

    //NOTE: This is a the 'lazy func def' pattern described at http://michaux.ca/articles/lazy-function-definition-pattern
    function formatMilliseconds(millis, data) {
        // Use jintervals if available, else default formatter
        var formatter;
        if (typeof jintervals == 'function') {
            formatter = function(millis, data){return jintervals(millis/1000, data.format);};
        } else {
            formatter = defaultFormatMilliseconds;
        }
        formatMilliseconds = function(millis, data) {
            return formatter(millis, data);
        };
        return formatMilliseconds(millis, data);
    }

    var methods = {

        init: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                updateInterval: 1000,
                startTime: 0,
                format: '{HH}:{MM}:{SS}',
                formatter: formatMilliseconds
            };

            // if (options) { $.extend(settings, options); }

            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');

                // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                if (!data) {
                    // Setup the stopwatch data
                    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                    data = settings;
                    data.active = false;
                    data.target = $this;
                    data.elapsed = settings.startTime;
                    // create counter
                    data.incrementer = incrementer(data.startTime, data.updateInterval);
                    data.tick_function = function() {
                        var millis = data.incrementer();
                        data.elapsed = millis;
                        data.target.trigger('tick.stopwatch', [millis]);
                        data.target.stopwatch('render');
                    };
                    $this.data('stopwatch', data);
                }

            });
        },

        start: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                // Mark as active
                data.active = true;
                data.timerID = setInterval(data.tick_function, data.updateInterval);
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        },

        stop: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                clearInterval(data.timerID);
                data.active = false;
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        },

        destroy: function() {
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                $this.stopwatch('stop').unbind('.stopwatch').removeData('stopwatch');
            });
        },

        render: function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('stopwatch');
            $this.html(data.formatter(data.elapsed, data));
        },

        getTime: function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('stopwatch');
            return data.elapsed;
        },

        toggle: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                if (data.active) {
                    $this.stopwatch('stop');
                } else {
                    $this.stopwatch('start');
                }
            });
        },

        reset: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                    data = $this.data('stopwatch');
                data.incrementer = incrementer(data.startTime, data.updateInterval);
                data.elapsed = data.startTime;
                $this.data('stopwatch', data);
            });
        }
    };


    // Define the function
    $.fn.stopwatch = function( method ) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.stopwatch' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks friend . its some perfect but when i click button again time is add to previous time for example when i click first time 00:5 time get then second click 00:6 time get then add two time and calculate..

Comment: can you re explain it? i dont understant your question

Comment: i said that   you use 'var timer = $('.timer').text(); ' when click button time get '00:03' now time is running and now click again and get time '00:07'
now i tell that add this time and get '00:10' if i click again then add time again

Comment: glad to hear that